# Use 1 single MySQL connection to provide result to multiple Users

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, node-modules

I have used one signle connection object of MYSQL in node JS to serve for multiple users.

I mean to say that MySQL connection will be created upon starting the script & it will remain same until the life of the node script/server.

Practically, this is possible to do & i have done the same. Please take a look at below code of NodeJS/MySQL script.

#################################

```
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');

 var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "192.168.1.105",
  user: "root",
  password: "XXXXXX",
  database: "mydb"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
     console.error('error: ' + err.message);
       process.exit(1);
  }

      http.createServer(function (req, res) {
         continueExecution(req,res);
      }).listen(8082);
  
});

async function continueExecution(req,res){

    res.write('calledddd\n');

    for (let step = 0; step < 50; step++) {
    // Runs 5 times, with values of step 0 through 4.
       var bar = `Company Inc ${step}`; 
       var sql = `INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES ('${bar}', 'Highway 37')`;

       res.write(sql + "\n");

      con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
       if (err) throw err;
         res.write("1 record inserted\n");
       });
    } 

     res.write('reached\n');
    for (let ste = 0; ste < 50; ste++) {

             res.write('started Update\n');
             var bar = `Company Inc ${ste}`; 
             var sql = `UPDATE customers SET name = 'UPDATE RECORD' WHERE name = '${bar}'`;
             con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
              res.write(result.affectedRows + " record(s) updated\n");

              if(ste == 50) {
                res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html\n'});
                res.write('Databse connected\n');

                 res.end();
               } 
            });
      }
}
```

#################################

I have several questions in my mind as i am technical expert. But i didn't find any resources over my questions. Please help me on this

Q1. Are there any type of consequences of using one single MySQL connection to provide response to multiple users?

Q2. Let's take an example.
100 users wants to access table name "users_data" at the same time. 25 users are updating their records on the same table with unique primary key. 50 users are selecting their records. another 25 users deleting their records.
All these operations are being done at the same time via parallel Node Script calls from remote device.

To complete all these MySQL transactions, system is using only 1 database connection.

What will happen in this case?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions, one of the consequences of using a unique connection is that it can lead to slower request execution.

In fact, even if node will make the requests asynchronously, your database will execute all those requests synchronously, so one after the other in the order they came. As node makes the requests asynchronously, the order in which they are executed by your database is not granted, and the issue you are referencing to might happen.

One easy way to avoid this is to use a connection pool which will create a given number of connection, using the same db user. Here are some links that might help you with this :

[using a connection pool with node.js](https://riptutorial.com/node-js/example/4587/using-a-connection-pool)

[connect a mysql database with node.js](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-nodejs/connect/)